# CUDA Kernel - Neural Net

Tags: c++, neural-network, cuda

I'm building a spiking neural net (recurrent, integrate and fire), and I'm curious about how to reduce the warp divergence (and other problems) I may have.
[Here's an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHILH3Dq-ro) with a few hand-placed neurons and synapses for a better apprehension. I upload the whole code on [a Git repo](https://bitbucket.org/Hyllis/spiking-neural-network-gpu) for faster access, `make tui` then `./cudasnn` to try.

The very basic workflow is to execute the 4 kernels (explanation in the comments) one after another.

After 5000 cycles, here's the time in ms for each kernel in order:

- 1 - 0.196ms
- 2 - 3.558ms
- 3 - 0.038ms
- 4 - 4.416ms to 6.278ms

My code is split into three files, whose name are pretty explicit.

**NN.hpp** (which contains my structures)

```
#ifndef NN_HPP
# define NN_HPP

# include <iostream>

/* Window Setting -- for SFML, no need here */
# define WIDTH              1280
# define HEIGHT             720
# define XOFFSET            -0
# define YOFFSET            -95

/* Network Settings */
# define STIMULUS           1
# define INHIBITION         -1
# define STIMULUS_RATIO     80
# define SPIKE_BUFFER       4

# define INPUT              0
# define OUTPUT             1
# define HIDDEN             2


typedef struct      s_neuron_info
{
    float           x, y, z;
    char            gid;
    unsigned char   group;          // hidden, input, output
}                   t_neuron_info;

typedef struct      s_neuron
{
    short           in_time;
    float           in_value;
    int             next_time;
    float           action_potential;
    float           threshold;      // fire when threshold reached
    float           weight;
    char            type;           // stimulus, inhibition
    char            carry;
}                   t_neuron;

typedef struct      s_synapse
{
    int             id_in;
    int             id_out;
    int             axonal_delay;   // in timestep
}                   t_synapse;

typedef struct      s_spike
{
    int             syn_id;
    int             id_out;
    int             start_t, end_t; // in timestep
    float           value;
    bool            active;
}                   t_spike;

typedef struct      s_network
{
    t_neuron        *neurons;
    t_neuron_info   *neurons_info;
    t_synapse       *synapses;
    t_spike         *spikes;
    int             neur_count;
    int             syn_count;
    int             timestep;
    int             group_size;
}                   t_network;

/* Generation */
t_network           *generate_network(void);

/* GPU Simulation */
float               simulate_network(t_network *nw);

#endif
```

**simulate_network.cu** (which contains the kernels and a small temporary main)

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include "NN.hpp"

#define cudaErrorAbort(msg) \
    { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "[CUDA Error] %s : %s (%s:%d)\n", \
                    msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                    __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    }


/* First Kernel
 * ============
 * Neuronal parallelism on the INPUT group,
 * check if an INPUT neuron should fire or not.
 */
__global__ void     check_input(t_neuron *n, int timestep)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (timestep >= n[idx].next_time)
    {
        n[idx].action_potential += n[idx].in_value;
        n[idx].next_time += n[idx].in_time;
    }
}

/* Second Kernel
 * =============
 * Synaptic parallelism, check pre-synaptic neurons
 * and create a spike if AP >= threshold
 */
__global__ void     check_synapses(t_neuron *n, t_synapse *s, t_spike *sp, int timestep, int scount)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j;

    if (n[s[idx].id_in].action_potential < n[s[idx].id_in].threshold)
        return ;
    n[s[idx].id_in].carry = 1;

    for (int i = idx * SPIKE_BUFFER; i < idx * SPIKE_BUFFER + SPIKE_BUFFER; ++i)
    {
        if (sp[i].active)
            continue;
        j = i;
        break ;
    }
    sp[j].syn_id = idx;
    sp[j].id_out = s[idx].id_out;
    sp[j].start_t = timestep;
    sp[j].end_t = timestep + s[idx].axonal_delay;
    sp[j].value = n[s[idx].id_in].action_potential * 0.2f * n[s[idx].id_in].type;
    sp[j].active = true;
}
__global__ void     carry_reset(t_neuron *n, int ncount)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;


    /* Might be faster depending of the architecture */
    // n[idx].action_potential -= (n[idx].carry * n[idx].action_potential);
    // n[idx].carry = 0;

    if (n[idx].carry)
    {
        n[idx].action_potential = 0.0f;
        n[idx].carry = 0;
    }
}

/* Third Kernel
 * ============
 * Process the "multi-circular" buffer by batch of SPIKE_BUFFER, and update
 * the AP of the post-synaptic neuron (+ kill the spike) if needed
 */
__global__ void     check_spikes(t_neuron *n, t_spike *sp, int timestep, int scount)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    for (int i = idx * SPIKE_BUFFER; i < idx * SPIKE_BUFFER + SPIKE_BUFFER; ++i)
    {
        if (timestep >= sp[i].end_t)
        {
            sp[i].active = false;
            sp[i].end_t = INT_MAX;      // to avoid the 'continue' branching
            n[sp[i].id_out].action_potential += (sp[i].value * n[sp[i].id_out].weight);

            if (n[sp[i].id_out].action_potential < 0.0f)
                n[sp[i].id_out].action_potential = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}

float       simulate_network(t_network *nw)
{
    static t_neuron     *neur_cptr = NULL;
    static t_synapse    *syn_cptr = NULL;
    static t_spike      *spike_cptr = NULL;
    static size_t       cp_size = sizeof(t_neuron) * ((nw->neur_count + 511) & ~511);
    static size_t       cp_syn_size = sizeof(t_synapse) * ((nw->syn_count + 511) & ~511);
    static size_t       cp_spike_size = sizeof(t_spike) * ((nw->syn_count + 511) & ~511) * SPIKE_BUFFER;

    /* add some more space to avoid useless conditions in kernel */

    if (!neur_cptr)
    {
        /* Malloc/cpy for neurons/synapses/spikes */
        cudaMalloc((void**) &neur_cptr, cp_size);
        cudaMemcpy(neur_cptr, nw->neurons, cp_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMalloc((void**) &syn_cptr, cp_syn_size);
        cudaMemcpy(syn_cptr, nw->synapses, cp_syn_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMalloc((void**) &spike_cptr, cp_spike_size);
        cudaMemcpy(spike_cptr, nw->spikes, cp_spike_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaErrorAbort("CUDA Malloc/Memcpy Error.");
    }

    /* Block size/N for kernel 1, 2 and 3 */
    int syn_block_size = 512 > nw->syn_count ? nw->syn_count : 512;
    int syn_block_count = nw->syn_count / syn_block_size
        + (!(nw->syn_count % syn_block_size) ? 0 : 1);
    int carry_block_size = 512 > nw->neur_count ? nw->neur_count : 512;
    int carry_block_count = nw->neur_count / carry_block_size
        + (!(nw->neur_count % carry_block_size) ? 0 : 1);

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsed_time;

    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    /* Kernel call */
    check_input <<< 1, nw->group_size >>> (neur_cptr, nw->timestep);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaErrorAbort("CUDA Kernel Error 1.");

    check_synapses <<< syn_block_count, syn_block_size >>> (neur_cptr,
            syn_cptr, spike_cptr, nw->timestep, nw->syn_count);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaErrorAbort("CUDA Kernel Error 2.");

    carry_reset <<< carry_block_count, carry_block_size >>> (neur_cptr, nw->neur_count);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaErrorAbort("CUDA Kernel Error 3.");

    check_spikes <<< syn_block_count, syn_block_size >>> (neur_cptr,
            spike_cptr, nw->timestep, nw->syn_count);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaErrorAbort("CUDA Kernel Error 4.");

    /* Timer */
    cudaEventCreate(&stop); cudaEventRecord(stop, 0); cudaEventSynchronize(stop); cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed_time, start, stop);
    printf("[%04d] Elapsed time: %f ms\n\n", nw->timestep, elapsed_time);
    cudaEventCreate(&start); cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    /* Cpy back */
    cudaMemcpy(nw->neurons, neur_cptr, cp_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(nw->synapses, syn_cptr, cp_syn_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(nw->spikes, spike_cptr, cp_spike_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaErrorAbort("CUDA Memcpy Error.");

    return (elapsed_time);
}

int         main(void)
{
    t_network   *nw;

    srand(time(NULL));
    if (!(nw = generate_network()))
        return (1);
    while (43)
    {
        simulate_network(nw);
        ++nw->timestep;
    }
    // return (0);
}
```

**generate_network.cpp** (which initialize my structures)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "NN.hpp"

int         randab(int a, int b)
{
    return (rand() % (b - a) + a);
}

double      frandab(double a, double b)
{
    return ((rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) * (b - a) + a);
}

void        init_neuron(t_neuron_info *nfo, t_neuron *ret, int id, int x, int y,
                    char type)
{
    nfo->x = x;
    nfo->y = y;
    nfo->z = 0;
    nfo->gid = id / 100;
    ret->in_value = frandab(0.8f, 3.0f);
    ret->in_time = randab(50, 100);
    ret->next_time = ret->in_time * frandab(0.2f, 1.0f);
    ret->action_potential = 0.0f;
    ret->threshold = frandab(6.5f, 10.5f);
    ret->weight = frandab(0.3f, 1.2f);
    ret->type = type;
    nfo->group = (nfo->gid == 0 ? INPUT : (nfo->gid == 1 ? OUTPUT : HIDDEN));
    ret->carry = 0;
}

void            init_synapse(t_synapse *ret, int in, int out)
{
    ret->id_in = in;
    ret->id_out = out;
    ret->axonal_delay = randab(5, 30);
}

t_network       *generate_network(void)
{
    t_network   *ret;

    if (!(ret = (t_network*)malloc(sizeof(t_network))))
        return (NULL);
    ret->timestep = 0;
    ret->group_size = 100;

    /* Alloc */
    ret->neur_count = 20000;
    if (!(ret->neurons = (t_neuron*)malloc(sizeof(t_neuron)
            * ((ret->neur_count + 511) & ~511)))
        || !(ret->neurons_info = (t_neuron_info*)malloc(sizeof(t_neuron_info)
            * ((ret->neur_count + 511) & ~511))))
        return (NULL);
    ret->syn_count = 400000;
    if (!(ret->synapses = (t_synapse*)malloc(sizeof(t_synapse)
            * ((ret->syn_count + 511) & ~511))))
        return (NULL);
    if (!(ret->spikes = (t_spike*)malloc(sizeof(t_spike)
            * ((ret->syn_count + 511) & ~511) * SPIKE_BUFFER)))
        return (NULL);

    /* Assign */
    for (int i = 0; i < ret->neur_count; ++i)
        init_neuron(&(ret->neurons_info[i]), &(ret->neurons[i]), i,
                (i / 12) * 11, (i % 60) * 18,
                randab(0, 100) >= STIMULUS_RATIO ? INHIBITION : STIMULUS);

    for (int i = 0; i < ret->syn_count; ++i)
    {
        int in = randab(0, ret->neur_count);
        int out = (randab(0, 2) || ret->neurons_info[in].gid == INPUT
                ? randab(0, ret->neur_count)
                : randab((int)(in / ret->group_size) * ret->group_size,
                    ((int)(in / ret->group_size) + 1) * ret->group_size));
        while (in == out)
            out = randab(0, ret->neur_count);
        init_synapse(&(ret->synapses[i]), in, out);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ret->syn_count * 4; ++i)
        ret->spikes[i].active = false;

    return (ret);
}
```

Everything should run nicely using:

> ```
> nvcc generate_network.cpp simulate_network.cu
> ```

Answer (score 2):

As a first step, remove as many conditional branches as possible. Take a functional programming approach.
You added a lot of conditional returns for error checking that can be removed if your arrays are set up to accommodate all inputs.

Conversion to functional programming example:

```
if (n[idx].carry)
{
  n[idx].action_potential = 0.0f;
  n[idx].carry = 0;
}
```

becomes:

```
n[idx].action_potential = n[idx].action_potential - (n[idx].carry * n[idx].action_potential);
n[idx].carry = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at my error checking -- in this example, won't it be a  loss to add maths to remove a condition which is at the end of the function anyway?

Comment: I try this, and unfortunately, I lose 0.02ms. -- and I don't really find any other condition that aren't essential.